# iText set up border color and width for check box, but it does not work

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I want to use iText to add a check box to a PDF file, and here is my code:

```java
    public static void testPdf() throws IOException {
        String src = "/Users/heartisan/Downloads/xx.pdf";
        String dest = "/Users/heartisan/Downloads/yy.pdf";
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            PdfButtonFormField checkField = PdfFormField.createCheckBox(pdf, new Rectangle(369 + i * 69, 751, 15, 15),
                    "experience".concat(String.valueOf(i+1)), "Off", PdfFormField.TYPE_CHECK);
            checkField.setBorderWidth(2);
            checkField.setBorderColor(DeviceGray.GRAY);
            checkField.setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);
            checkField.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.RED);
            checkField.setToggleOff(false);
//            checkField.getWidgets().get(0).setBorderStyle(PdfAnnotation.STYLE_SOLID);
            form.addField(checkField, pdf.getPage(1));
        }
        document.close();
    }
```

Then here is the result:
[image]

Actually, as the code showed before, I set up the border color and width, but it just not work, I used Adobe Arcobat and it works:
[image]

Then I debugged the two files' fields, and I found:
[image]

As I marked, both the color and width's values are gone, both the values were there just before I call document.close(), I don't know why.

**Can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 0):

Is it expected result if you open your resultant PDF in Google Chrome or Pdf Studio 2020? I have the same result In Acrobat so I think it's not an issue of iText. Btw, If you click on your checkFields in Acrobat, all looks as expected.